# Can BeEF also work in public?

Tags: xss, attacks, web, beef

Is it possible to run the tool called BeEF to do penetration testing on real domains like example.com? As far as I know, BeEF can only be used within localhost.

I can only test my site for XSS on the real domain because of the database running.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's absolutely possible to use this tool in public...

## However

Beef is a browser exploitation tool, not a server exploitation tool. If you use beef to attack browsers of other people, who have **not given explicit consent to being attacked**, then you are likely committing an unlawful act, depending on your jurisdiction.

So yes, technically it is possible. But no, it is likely not lawful and I would recommend against doing it.

Comment: @schroeder  I wish I could at least say goodbye to my friends, but this will have to do. I can tell I am no longer welcome here by the powers that be, so I'll exit stage left. It's been lovely. I'll miss you all.

Comment: Well, then I'm sorry that things didn't work out. You always did a great job here. I'll miss it.

Comment: Sorry, then. See you and thanks for all your contributions.

Comment: I'll miss you and your answers and comments as well, @MechMK1.